# How to display HTML text in Flutter in desktop

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a paragraph in HTML that has various bold text and links within the tag using flutter on a desktop platform. I've come across "flutter_html", but the only supported platforms are for iOS and Android. Is there any other library that could display HTML text in a desktop environment? If there are none, are there any other ways to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flutter_html in desktop app.

Try my code below:

```dart
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(title: 'This Is Desktop'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    parseHtml();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<dom.Document> parseHtml() async {
    return parse(await rootBundle.loadString('static/index.html'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<dom.Document>(
          future: parseHtml(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dom.Document> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Html(data: snapshot.data?.outerHtml);
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: Text("Loading"),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

However, some tag has no effect. For example `img` tag not showing image, `a` tag only have link style but won't open a browser to a link when you click on it.

And some of css styles are not support, like flex.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you so much. However, I'm curious about the possible workarounds for tags that have no effects.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not digging into why it doesn't work. 
BTW, I found that `img` tag work when I put the image url link, but not local image file path.

Comment: html parser parse html into flutter class `Document` though, I don't think the `Document` work 100% same as html in browser.